# Plot day to day execution time duration for list of items

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-chart

I am having the below data

```
Items   Date      Start Time  End time  
App 1   10/27/2017   1:00     13:00  
App 2   10/27/2017  14:00     15:00  
App 3   10/27/2017  17:00     20:00  
App 1   10/28/2017   1:00     13:00  
App 2   10/28/2017  14:00     15:00  
App 3   10/28/2017  17:00     20:00  
App 1   10/29/2017   1:00     13:00  
App 2   10/29/2017  14:00     15:00  
App 3   10/29/2017  17:00     20:00
```

and i need to create a chart like the attached image.  Please help me to create a chart like this using excel or some other tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to calculate duration of your activities, you can do it with e.g. this formula:
`=(D2-C2)*24`

Then insert a pivot chart and set it:

- select your data and go to insert - charts - pivot chart
- select the columns:

  - legend (series): "items"
  - axis (categories): "date"
  - values: "duration"

    - it'll automatically calculate "sum of duration", as you've only one data per item & date, that's probably fine, but you can change it as you like
- finally right click on your chart, select "change chart type" and select "stacked column"

[image]

Comment: The chart looks good.  But my requirement is slightly different.  The legend area (Items) is based on Duration.  I want it based on Start time and End time.  Y axis should be time and app 1 should fill the legend area exactly from 1 to 13 and not from 0 to 12.